# ASA 5512-X Can't access VLAN Gateway

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan, cisco-asa, nat

I have those 3 Interfaces configured:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address PUBLICIP 255.255.255.240 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 no nameif
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.200.0.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3.99
 vlan 99
 nameif servers
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.16.18.1 255.255.255.0                                                                                                 
!
```

also I have a default route

```
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 ISP_GATEWAY 1
```

and these NAT Rules

```
nat (inside,servers) source static any any
nat (inside,outside) source static any interface unidirectional description Internetaccess
```

also

```
enable traffic between two or more interfaces which are configured with same security levels
```

and

```
enable traffic between two or more hosts connected to the same interface
```

activated.

I am able to go on the internet with the "inside" network. But I can't ping the Gateway 172.16.18.1. Also, i have a client on Interface 3 connected with the ip 172.16.18.168/24 with the gateway 172.16.18.1. This client is alsp not able to ping 172.16.18.1.

In ASDM, I'm able to ping the Gateway from the servers interface. What am I missing? I read [here](http://blog.braini.ac/?p=38) that i have to configure for every VLAN I have, a NAT-Statement. Is this true? Because I need 10 VLANs.

I can't figure out what I'm missing. When I do Packet tracer in ASDM no ACL seems to block it.

PS: the two clients are directly connected to the ports.
PS:PS: I am configuring 80% over ASDM and 20% over CLI (the way I learned in school).

Comment: By default ASA block ICMP, you have to explicitly allow it.

Comment: It is allowed:
'policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
  inspect icmp 
  inspect http 
!'

Comment: You really need to include the whole configuration. Also the configuration of the switch attached to the ASA.

Comment: I think this command nat (inside,servers) source static any any  is incorrect.  What are you trying to do with this NAT?

Comment: @RonMaupin There is no Switch attached, I'm just testing it. Switch didn't arrive yet. 
ATTrunk Tell that every IP from the network inside should be translated to the network servers without changing source and destination IP. Read it here: http://blog.braini.ac/?p=38

Currently not at work, so i can't edit the while conf.

Comment: Do you have a device which understands VLAN tags? Most end-devices don't understand VLAN tags. The switch will give non-tagged frames to the end devices in each VLAN. I'm not sure you can properly test this without a switch.

Comment: ouh really? Which switch doesn't matter? A normal unmanaged should do the work too?

Answer (score 1):

1.The FW is setup to work like that, you are only able to ping the interface that you are connected to, so if you are on the inside subnet you wont be able to ping the Servers interface nor the outside interface only the inside interface. In addition when it is traffic TO the box it does not check the ACLs, only for traffic that goes THROUGH the box is checked with the ACLs, now if you could attach the output from the "show run icmp" command I could confirm if you have any miss-configuration  there that is preventing the ICMP requests for that interface.

2.If all vlans require internet access then yes, you would need to configure a NAT statement for each one of them, now if it is going to be accessed only from users on the inside there really is no need for the NAT since routing should be enough.

PD: It would be useful if you setup a capture in the interface to confirm that the ICMP message reach the interface, or plug-in the device directly to the interface to run the test.